# Laravel - Show all fields on blade where checkbox is true

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page on my website `Example Trips`. I want to display trip itineraries here which users have created and set to `Public` as in to allow any users of the website to view.

Users can currently view their own personal trips on the 'View Trips' page.

On another page `Plan a trip`, I have a form where users enter trip details. At the end there is a checkbox option `Public` which users can tick on leave blank.

I have a `TripContoller` and `EventContoller`. One Trip can have many events.

On my `ExampleItineraies.blade.php` I'd like to show all trips along with events of the trip where `$trip->is_public` is set to true.

What's the best way for me to do this?

**CreateTrip.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('public', 'Make Trip Itinerary Public') !!}
        {!! Form::checkbox('public', 'value'); !!}
</div>
```

[image: Trip Table in database]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you display your `ExampleItineraies` view for a `Trip` you can simply wrap the the portion of the template you want to be public in an `@if($trip->public) @endif` like so:

```
@if ($trip->public)
    @forelse ($trip->events as $event)
        ... display your event ...
    @empty
        This trip doesn't currently have any events
    @endforelse
@endif
```